# What utilities will allow me to see how much network data a process has used in a session?

Tags: networking, monitoring, utilities

I need to know how much network data each program/process are using on my machine.  There are great tools (like [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/)) to give me information on current usage.  However, it does not give me cumulative stats.  [darkstat](https://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/) also looks great, but it only shows data at the host level (not the process level like I need).  Something like the [Android data usage tool](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/monitor-data-usage-android,news-21226.html) would be great.

What are some tools that will allow me to see how much network data each process has used over a given amount of time?

Comment: I think you'll have to define what you mean by "how much data a process has used" in order to get a good answer to this. To me, it could mean the largest amount of memory it was using at any point (in case its memory usage goes up and down over time) or it could mean the amount of data that it has received or generated (or both, if it is a filter), etc...

Comment: Are you talking about network traffic, or disk traffic, or CPU usage, or what? And on what Unix variant? I don't think Linux tracks network traffic by default, for example. And tracking per application, rather than per user as in Android (Android apps run as different users), is difficult.

Comment: Haha, sorry it is pretty confusing without the word "network" in front of "data".  I updated the title and question.

Comment: And if we need to get even more specific, any IP packets sent over a network interface.